# Error when loading data from HDFS to Hive on Azure Hdinsight

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

I am using Hadoop on Azure HDinsight.

On my Hadoop cluster storage container, I have created a file share called "tempdata" and upload the file "his2.csv".

On hive , I created a table "temps_his" to hold data of "his2.csv" into.I ran the following query :

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/admin/tempdata/his2.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE temp_his;
```

( admin is my username)

I got the following error:

```
 Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/user/admin/tempdata/his2.csv'': No files matching path wasb://saadcluster@saadcluster.blob.core.windows.net/user/admin/tempdata/his2.csv [ERROR_STATUS]
```

How can I fix this and get the exact path of the file?

Answer (score 0):

either put file in hdfs or add "local " in command .
LOAD DATA local INPATH '/user/admin/tempdata/his2.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE temp_his;

Comment: I figure out that I wasn't storing on blob storage. So even the suggested query won't work